# Why is the solution space of this system not a linear subspace?

Tags: matrices

For the following system:

$$
\begin{align}
x+y+z&=1\\
x+2y+2z&=0\\
2y-z&=5
\end{align}
$$
the reduced row echelon form is

$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0&2\\0&1&0&\frac{4}{3}\\0&0&1&-\frac{7}{3}}
$$

Is the space of the solution for this system **not** a linear subspace of in $\\R^3$ because the solution a single point in $\\R^3$?

Answer (score 4):

For an **inhomogeneous** system, like this one, the solution set is a coset of a linear subspace.  In this case, it is a coset of the zero linear subspace.